# Separate the Pandas DataFrame by commas and '\n'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

I have this dataframe which i want to clean up. More specifically i want to separate the inputs between all the commas, '\n' etc. to separate columns, but i can not get it to work.

[picture of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKs59.png)

The data is from a web scraping project:

```
listing_data = []
for data in list_html0:
    inner_rows1 = data.find_all('a', class_='listing-item-chips')
    listing_data += inner_rows1
    

merged_df=pd.DataFrame(listing_data)

merged_df
```